# I want access on the basis of ID. When I click Details Option I want only that ID data will show on page

Tags: php, mysql

```
if (isset($_GET['pro_id'])){    
$product_id = $_GET['pro_id']; $get_pro = "select * from products"; $run_pro = mysqli_query($con, $get_pro);
while ($row_pro = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro)){
$pro_id = $row_pro['product_id'];

        $pro_title = $row_pro['product_title'];
        $pro_price = $row_pro['product_price'];
        $pro_image = $row_pro['product_image'];
        //$pro_desc = $row_pro['product_desc'];
        echo "
        <div id = 'single_product'>
        <h3>$pro_title</h3>
        <img src='admin_area/product_images/$pro_image' width='400' height='300' />
        <p><b>Rs. $pro_price</b></p>
        <a href='index.php' style='float:left;'>Go Back</a><br>
        <a href='index.php?pro_id=$pro_id'><button style='float:right;'>Add to Cart</button></a>
        </div>  
        ";
        }
        }   
                    ?>
```

Comment: Some explanation is required. What doesn't work with the code that you've posted there?

Comment: nothing happened.. only blank page show to me

Comment: I have details link in index page and i want access any specific detail of any product another page called details.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the product you want to fetch in your SQL Query. The one you are using, `$get_pro = "select * from products";` fetches all the products. You want to change it to this:

```
$get_pro = "select * from products WHERE product_id=".((int)$product_id);
```

So it only selects one product, the one that is passed in `$_GET['pro_id']`.

Comment: I am doing such like

$get_pro = "select * from products where product_id='$product_id'";

Comment: URL link show correct URL of that product's detail but page is nothing showing

Comment: Do you have anything in your `products` table? And you are passing `?pro_id=something` in your url?

Comment: nothing happened.. only blank page show to me. format which i set that show only. which i want that that are not showing

Comment: i am designing E-commerce website and i have products and i want when user click on products then details.php will show and show detail of specific product. URL is correct but details are not showing. <div> where i want detail that empty(show nothing)

Comment: i have data on products tables that i want show on my my php page from database